# How to debug a fluid email template?

Tags: typo3, fluid, email-templates, typo3-11.x

In typo3/fluid you can use the <f:debug> viewhelper to print out some or all available template variables. On a webpage template this is printed out at the top of the screen. But how to do this inside an email template?

I would expect an output of the <f:debug>-Viewhelper at some place. Maybe inside the email or somewhere in the typo3 log files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<f:debug> has handy "inline" and "plainText" attributes, so you can actually inline the output at exactly the place where the viewhelper is placed. Try that one! :)

https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Debug.html#inline

&

https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Debug.html#plaintext

Comment: Sorry, that does not work in email templates, at least not in typo3 v11.5. Tried that in plain and html template.

Comment: Sorry! You are completely right. You also need the "inline='true'" argument! See https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Debug.html#inline

Comment: With the inline attribute this works. So the important part is the inline attribute, but the plainText could help for text emails. Can you change your answer to reflekt this?